# How to return autoincrement value in insert query in SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, auto-increment

In my project I use [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/). Database has table `Tags`, which contains autoincrement primary field `ID` (type `Integer`). When I write:

```
using (SQLiteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   command.CommandText = "insert into Tags(name) values(@name) returning into @id";
   command.Parameters.Add("@id", DbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Visual Studio said that the operation is not supported. How to fix it?

Error occurs on line:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@id", DbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: Where's the working code? I have the same problem, but I find "SELECT last_insert_rowid()" to be annoyingly vague. How is @name set? Where does "SELECT last_insert_rowid()" go? Aside: What functionality have you added to Calibre? ;)

Comment: I think, you can't to set @name. You key must have name 'Id'. "SELECT last_insert_rowid()" work with last insert.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found working query:

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

Comment: How does that work? I get syntax error:INSERT STATEMENT INSERT INTO Orders (NAME) VALUES (@P0)  SELECT last_insert_rowid()

Answer (score 2):

SQLite 3.35.0 and newer supports [RETURNING](https://sqlite.org/lang_returning.html) clause:

> The RETURNING clause is designed to provide the application with the values of columns that are filled in automatically by SQLite.

The code could look like:

```
INSERT INTO Tags(name) VALUES(@name) RETURNING ID;
```

Answer (score -1):

I advice to use Stored Procedure.

IN SQL Server has `@@IDENTITY` system Variable . it returns the last autoincrement value

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPGetLastAutoInc @name varchar, @lastAutoResult INT OUTPUT AS

INSERT INTO Tags(name) values(@name)


SET @lastAutoResult = @@IDENTITY

-- Return the number of all items ordered.
RETURN lastAutoResult 
GO
```

Comment: Sorry. i did not know that you are using SQLite . It works in SqlServer